# Changing DNS settings in openwrt uci command line

Tags: dns, router, openwrt, uci

How can I change the DNS settings using the command line in an openwrt router?
I see these files here [here](https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/base-system/uci)

`/etc/config/ddns`
`/etc/config/ipset-dns`
But I slo see dnsmasq installed

but not sure which can change the DNS servers on the router

My end goal is to add a cron job that adds a custom DNS for couple of hours per day, then revert to the original DNS

**Edit:** I've found the following commands, can anybody explain?

`uci set network.wan.dns='<list of space-separated DNS server IPs>'`

`uci commit network`

`reload_config`

and

`uci set network.wan.peerdns='0'`

`uci del network.wan.dns`

`uci add_list network.wan.dns='9.9.9.9'`

`uci add_list network.wan.dns='149.112.112.112'`

`uci commit`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can forward DNS requests to specific servers by doing:

`uci add_list dhcp.@dnsmasq[0].server="SERVER_ADDRESS"`

`uci commit dhcp`

`service dnsmasq restart` or `/etc/init.d/dnsmasq restart`

You can read more about this here: https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/base-system/dhcp_configuration (scroll down or find 'DNS forwarding')